# How to change html input multiple value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `html` input field like this:

```
<input name="files[]" id="files" type="file" style="display: none;" onchange="saveFile();" multiple="true" />
```

How can i change multiple's value to `false` using `javascript`?

Comment: Where is your code? You have tried something on your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [**`.setAttribute()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute)

> **Syntax:** `element.setAttribute(attributename,attributevalue)`

Your code should look like this

```
document.getElementById("files").setAttribute("multiple","false");
```

Comment: Actually i tried that before, but it didn't work because the problem was elsewhere in the code. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery way for this would be

```
 $('input:file[name="some_name"]').attr('multiple', 'false');
```